# ¿Cómo definir una variable PHP, que pase por parámetro a una función onclick?

Tags: php, javascript, html

¿Cómo definir una variable `PHP`, que pase por parámetro, por un input tipo button, con una función `onclick` que lo lee un JavaScript? PHP a JS

> ERROR: variable_solicitada is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

PHP:

```
if ($consulta->num_rows > 0) {
    $nuevoArreglo = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
        $id=$row["Code"];
        echo $row["Name"]." <input type='button' id='info' value='Informacion' onclick='informacion(".$id.")'><br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "No se encotraron resultados";
}
?>
```

JS:

```
function informacion(code){
alert(code);}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para entrar en contexto,el `echo $row["Name"]." input type='button' id='info' value='Informacion' onclick='informacion(".$id.")'><br>"` es el Botón que dice Información cuando yo le doy `click` al dicho botón me debería aparecer un `alert` con el `code` o mas bien dicho el $id(contenido de la variable que esta en el PHP) del país.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido JJsCR, el error que muestra no coincide con el código agregado ? ¿Donde declara `variable_solicitada`?  tal y como está debería funcionar

Comment: Gracias Dev. Joel, te comparto la imagen donde me tira el error, no la variable_solicitada es en este caso el $id=$row["Code"]; en cual yo necesito para poder seguir ejecutando mi código, no me funciona no se si es por problemas de sintaxis si es así por favor comuníquemelo.

Comment: Hola, consulta, estas seguro que tu consulta trae estos dos campos? (Code, Name), prueba poniendole un var_dump($row); para que te vaya mostrando el valor de la fila.

Otra cosa, si no ocuparas mas campos que estos dos, seria mejor reemplazar el * por el nombre de ellos

Comment: Buenas Ariel Navarrete, la consulta si me trae los datos de la base de datos satisfactoriamente y son los correctos, es que la consulta por la cual hago SELECT * FROM es por luego es variable la voy a necesitar mas adelante para mostrar mas datos del país. Te pongo una imagen de la pagina para entrar en contexto de lo que me quiero desarrollar.

Comment: Ignore la variable_solicitada ya que para este momento no existe ya, ABW es el código del país es el que yo ocupo pero me tira error, el error se da al traspasar la variable de $id al JavaScript para tener su valor,

Comment: Pregunta: te da error al cargar la pagina, o solo cuando haces click en alguno de los botones que has creado en esa parte de php? en cualquier caso, muestra por favor el codigo que te ha generado el navegador en esa parte.

Comment: @JJsCR al parece esta generando problemas con las comillas, si no estoy equivocado deberia quedar asi 
    echo $row["Name"]." <input type='button' id='info' value='Informacion' onclick='informacion(\"$id\")'><br>";

Notese que escape las comillas dobles de la variable $id (\"), y como esta esto dentro de la misma linea y se estan ocupando comillas dobles no es necesario colocar punto para unirlo.
Y mis disculpas por no formatear el bloque de codigo, hace tiempo que no entro a esto y no recuerdo como ocupar todos los comandos xD

Comment: Solo cuando me hace click en cualquier botón, en el caso de arriba presión United States y me sale error pero lo curioso es que en el error lee el código del país diciendo: USA not defined at .....etc

Comment: @ArielNavarrete te invito a agregar una respuesta con tu último comentario. creo que es lo más cercano a una solución.

Comment: Listo ERROR Solucionado gracias Ariel Navarrete Crack! solo bueno.

Comment: Perfecto, dejare la respuesta formateada entonces xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formateo la solución propuesta

```
echo $row["Name"]." <input type='button' id='info' value='Informacion' 
       onclick='informacion(\"$id\")'><br>";
```

Nótese que se cambio:

1) Se escapo las comillas dobles de la variable $id `(\")`

2) Como esta esto dentro de la misma linea y se estan ocupando comillas dobles no es necesario colocar punto para unirlo.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Ariel Navarrete me has solucionado el problema.

Comment: Como detalle, indicar que el problema es realmente que el valor de $id son cadenas de caracteres, no numeros, y que cuando se compone en el php, la funcion en javascript queda como   informacion(abc); con lo cual javascript intenta interpretar abc como variable. La solucion, no obstante, es la que indica Ariel navarrete, es añadir comillas en la creacion de la funcion. Ariel, si te parece añade esta informacion a tu solucion, para dejar claro el tema